# AWS EMR migration from us-east to us-west

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, emr, amazon-emr

I am planning to move an emr cluster from us-east to us-west. I have data residing in hdfs as well as s3. But due to lack of proper documentation i am unable to start with this thing.
Does anyone has any experience in doing so ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [s3-dist-cp](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/UsingEMR_s3distcp.html) tool on EMR to copy data from HDFS to S3 and later , you can use the same tool to copy from S3 to HDFS on the cluster in different region. Also note that its always recommended to use EMR with s3 buckets on same region.